# How to position an input tag in a div

Tags: html, css

I have recently tried to position a "username" and "password" field in a div which it's background has some graphics. In the graphics, I need a text field to be positioned and sized. I have a live view at the front page of "spaggit.com". Here is my CSS code:

```
#pageFrontMiddle {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    height: 590px;
    background: url('/images/frontImage.png') no-repeat;
}
```

and here is the image:http://www.spaggit.com/images/frontImage.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
-Jaydon.

Comment: Curious design choice to be putting input fields on top of a single image... may I ask why?

Comment: I thought it would be simpler..

Comment: If anything it'll make it *more* difficult as you'll have to juggle editing and re-uploading your image as well as the CSS to properly align your fields; it adds a lot more steps in the design process (and that's just *one* of the drawbacks). Have you wondered why any major website *doesn't* do this?

Answer (score 1):

Although this is NOT how you should develop your website, here is how you can do it:

Just put `relative` positioning on the Image Wrapper and `absolute` positioning on the Inputs and mess with the `height, width, top and left` properties.

```
#pageFrontMiddle #input_username {
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
    height: 51px;
    width: 365px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 289px;
    left: 466px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NoahWetjen/g8W3g/)

Comment: Thanks :) You said it's NOT the way to design my website. How would I do it without this method?